# Polymer data binding with Javascript and attributes

Tags: javascript, html, data-binding, attributes, polymer

I'm working on a project about doctors information and i'm doing this with polymer 1.0. Well, i have some trouble and even Google couldn't help me a lot.

I have 3 Components: a vaadin-grid (basically a list of the doctors) called **doctors-grid**, a modal dialog called **doctor-dialog** and the content of the modal dialog (which contains the information about the selected doctor) called **doctor-details**. I've separated the Content and the modal dialog in 2 components, because my teacher told me to.

In my vaadin-grid, i'm getting the data from a json (btw i'm doing this **without** iron-ajax). And in this list, i can select a doctor by double click and the modal dialog with the details of the doctor opens in it. I'm saving the selected doctor in an variable called "selecteddoctor".

Now to my problem: When the modal dialog opens, i want the data from the selected doctor to be shown in the content. For example in the content should be shown something like this

[How it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ysuF.png)

[How it actually looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaoGS.png)

For doctor-details i created an attribute called **doctordata**. I'm not sure but i think that the selected doctor should now be put in the attribute doctordata like **doctordata = "selecteddoctor"**. 
But i don't know how to get the selected doctor from the vaadin grid to my doctor-details component and how to define it to the doctordata attribute.

So my question is: How can i get the selected doctor to the modal dialog and from there to the doctor details, to show the doctors information in the modal dialog?

**doctors-grid code**

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html"/>
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/vaadin-grid/vaadin-grid.html"/>

<dom-module id="doctors-grid">
    <template>
        <vaadin-grid id="doctors-grid">
            <table>
                <colgroup>
                 .......
                </colgroup>
            </table>
        </vaadin-grid>
    </template>

<script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'doctors-grid'
    });
    (function() {
        HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
            var grid = document.getElementById('doctors-grid');
            var doctors = [];
            var selecteddoctor = null;

            getJSON('/json/doctors.json', function(json) {
                doctors = json;
                grid.items = doctors;
                grid.refreshItems();
            });


            grid.addEventListener('selected-items-changed', function() {
                var selectedindex = grid.selection.selected();

                if(selectedindex.length > 0){
                  selecteddoctor = doctors[selectedindex[0]];
                  console.log('Selected: ' + grid.selection.selected());
                }
              });

              grid.addEventListener('dblclick', function() {
                  modaldoctordialog.open(); -->This is the modal dialog
                  console.log('Doubleclick: ' + selectedarzt.name); -->this works
                });
        });

        function getJSON(url, callback) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
                    callback(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
                }
            };
            xhr.open('GET', url, true);
            xhr.send();
        }
    })();
</script>
```

**doctor-dialog code**

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/paper-dialog/paper-dialog.html"/>
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/paper-dialog-scrollable/paper-dialog-scrollable.html"/>
<link rel="import" href="../doctor-details/doctor-details.html"/>

<dom-module id="doctor-dialog">
  <template>
    <paper-dialog id="modaldoctordialog" modal>
      <paper-dialog-scrollable>
        <div class="content">
          <doctor-details doctordata="WHAT COMES IN HERE?"></doctor-details>
        </div>
      </paper-dialog-scrollable>
      <paper-button dialog-dismiss>Cancel</paper-button>
      <paper-button>Modify</paper-button>
    </paper-dialog>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
    is: 'doctor-dialog',
  });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

**doctor-details code**

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/paper-material/paper-material.html"/>
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html"/>

<dom-module id="doctor-details">
  <template>
    <style>
      .......
    </style>


    <div class="block">
      <paper-material elevation="1">Doctor</paper-material>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Name</td>
          <td><paper-input label = "{{doctordata.name}}" disabled></paper-input></td> --> the label should be correct but when I open the dialog the input field is empty
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Forename</td>
          <td><paper-input label = "{{doctordata.forename}}></paper-input></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

    .....
    .....

  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
    is: 'doctor-details',
    properties: {
                doctordata: {
                    type: Object,
                    value: null
                }
            }
    }); --> here i created the attribute doctordata
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

I really hope someone can help me because it's a really important project.
I'm thankful for every help I can get.

Comment: Where do you import your doctor-dialog code ?

Comment: @sebastian Nowhere, because i open the dialog with the ID in the doubleclick function. 

--> modaldoctordialog.open();

I also tried with importing the doctor-dialog code at the doctors-grid code but it didnt make a difference.

Comment: But you have imported the doctor-dialog element somewhere in your code?

Comment: @sebastian
yes before i used to import the doctor-dialog on the index.html because i opened the dialog with a paper-button but now changed this to open it with the double click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(removed earlier answer as it is not needed anymore)

**Update #2**

After I seen your code, it works:

You have to implement your Basic HTML functions to the Polymer `ready` function. 
Your complete code now looks like this:

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html"/>
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/vaadin-grid/vaadin-grid.html"/>
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/paper-dialog/paper-dialog.html"/>
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/paper-dialog-scrollable/paper-dialog-scrollable.html"/>
<link rel="import" href="../arzt-details/arzt-details.html"/>

<dom-module id="aerzte-grid">
  <link rel="import" type="css" href="../../css/paper-buttons-style.css">
    <template>
        <style>
            #sort {
                height: 300px;
            }

        </style>

        <vaadin-grid id="aerzte-grid">
            <table>
                <colgroup>
                    <col name="vorname" sortable/>
                    <col name="name" sortable/>
                    <col name="adresseNr" sortable/>
                    <col name="plz" sortable/>
                    <col name="ort" sortable/>
                    <col name="telefon"/>
                </colgroup>
            </table>
        </vaadin-grid>

        <!--Modales Fenster-->
        <paper-dialog id="arztdialog" modal>
          <paper-dialog-scrollable>
            <div class="content">
              <!-- Change arztdata to arztdetaildata, we won't use the whole object -->
              <arzt-details arztdata="{{arztdetaildata}}"></arzt-details>
            </div>
          </paper-dialog-scrollable>
          <paper-button dialog-dismiss>Abbrechen</paper-button>
          <paper-button>Bearbeiten</paper-button> <!--Falls auf Bearbeiten geklickt wird, soll sich dieser Button zu "Speichern" ändern und die paper-inputs auf enabled setzen-->
        </paper-dialog>

    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'aerzte-grid',
              properties: {
                // We have one global object with all data
                arztdata: {
                  type: Object,
                  notify: true
                },
                // we have a detail object that holds just the data for the current doctor
                arztdetaildata: {
                  type: Object,
                  notify: true
                }
            },
            // register the double-click-event listener
            listeners: {
              'dblclick': 'onDblClick'
            },
            ready: function() {
              // this is important, because 'this' is not applicable inside of whenReady()
              var that = this;
              HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
                  var grid = document.getElementById('aerzte-grid');
                  var aerzte = [];
                  var selectedarzt = null;

                  that.getJSON('/json/aerzte.json', function(json) {
                      aerzte = json;
                      grid.items = aerzte;
                      grid.refreshItems();
                  });

                  grid.addEventListener('sort-order-changed', function() {
                      var sortOrder = grid.sortOrder[0];
                      var sortProperty = grid.columns[sortOrder.column].name;
                      var sortDirection = sortOrder.direction;
                      grid.items.sort(function(a, b) {
                          var res;
                          var path = sortProperty.split('.');
                          for (var i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
                              a = a[path[i]];
                              b = b[path[i]];
                          }
                          if (!isNaN(a)) {
                              res = parseInt(a, 10) - parseInt(b, 10);
                          } else {
                              res = a.localeCompare(b);
                          }

                          if ('desc' === sortDirection) {
                              res *= -1;
                          }
                          return res;
                      });
                  });
                  grid.addEventListener('selected-items-changed', function() {
                      var selectedindex = grid.selection.selected();

                      if(selectedindex.length > 0){
                        selectedarzt = aerzte[selectedindex[0]];
                        // i replaced arztdata with that.arztdetaildata, so it is in polymers scope and can be bound to elements
                        that.arztdetaildata = selectedarzt;
                        console.log('Selected: ' + grid.selection.selected());
                      }
                    });

              });
            },
            getJSON: function(url, callback) {
                  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                      if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
                          callback(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
                      }
                  };
                  xhr.open('GET', url, true);
                  xhr.send();
            },
            // double-click-handler, logs the detail json object
            onDblClick: function() {
              arztdialog.open();
              console.log('arzt-detail-data', this.arztdetaildata);
            },
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

I also moved your double-click-listener to a Polymer listener. Just replace your `aerzte-grid.html` with this code, and it works like a charm :-)

Please not the annotated sections. They are important.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! :-)
But where do you use "<doctor-dialog doctordata="{{doctordata}}"></doctor-dialog>"? because i'm opening the dialog just with the double click function  by modaldoctordialog.open();

Comment: Yes - that can cause a problem ;-) Let me update my answer ;-)

Comment: Okay i made it the easy way and just implementet the paper-dialog to the doctors-grid, so there isn't a doctor-dialog any more.
Sadly it still doesn't work :-(
I made everything like you explained but there is still no data shown in my doctor-details

Comment: Sorry, overseen: try `paper-input label$="{{doctordata.name}}"...` (note the `$` before the `=`.

Comment: Now it's time I should see the complete code... can you provide a jsfiddle (or similar)?

Comment: I made a fiddle once but a really really simple one like Hello World. So I don't really know how this works with more complex projects.
Is it okay if I just give you the link to my Dropbox?
https://www.dropbox.com/s/r8mw904occmdaa3/WebContent.zip?dl=0

In the src folder are doctors-grid and doctor-details. doctors-overview is like my index.html
**I actually named the files in german (just wrote it in english here so everyone understands) but I think you should understand get this.
Note: Arzt/Aerzte means doctor/doctors ;-)**

Comment: @BlueCat Check the comments to your dropbox-file, i added a link to the updated version